# Outer loop is being called more than once, while Calling TaskList in Durable Function with Nested Loop for fan-out approach

Tags: c#, azure-functions, nested-loops, azure-durable-functions

Here is a simplified code of my "Orchestrator":

```
  [FunctionName("Orchestrator")]
    public static async Task<bool> RunOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger logger)
    {

        List<string> hashKeyList = new List<string>();
        List<Task<CalcResult>> tasksList = new List<Task<CalcResult>>();
        Dictionary<A, B> otherCalc = new Dictionary<A, B>();
        List<FinalResult> finalResults = new List<FinalResult>();

        foreach (var a in A)//LOOP A
        {
            foreach (var b in B)//LOOP B
            {
                var hashKey = doSomeThingOnAandB(a, b);
            if (!hashKeyList.Contains(hashKey))
                {
                    hashkeyList.Add(hashKey);
                    tasksList.Add(context.CallActivityAsync<CalcResult>
                        (nameof(CalculationActivity), (a, b)));
                }
            else
                {
                    otherCalc.Add(a, b);
                }
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(tasksList);

            foreach (var task in tasksList)
            {
                var res = ((Task<caclResult>)task).Result;

                finalResults.Add(res);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to create a nested loop for my durable function. All the examples are always for one loop, and in my case, the inner loop (B) is working properly. However, the outer loop (A) is repeated more than once!

**In my scenario:**
In some cases, `a` and `b` combinations are going to be equal. I am creating a "hashkey" with some small calculations on objects `a` and `b`, if the combination is already mentioned I will insert them in `otherCalc` dictionary, otherwise it will be added to `taskList`.

**What is happening:**
All the `a` and `b`s are inserting to `otherCalc`. "Loop A" restarts although the `hashKeyList` is keeping it's content. This means Regardless of the previous runs of the outer loop (Loop A), which already filled the `hashKeyList`, I see all the A list is called again.

Comment: Why don't you utilize your ilogger to see how many times the method is called or what's the length of the outer loop? Try to harvest as much information as you can.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, because i never worked with Azure-Functions, but how can you code snippet be valid C#? `A` and `B` have to be Types, because of the declaration of `Dictionary<A, B> otherCalc` and also have to be instances of some type, because of the `foreach` loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely, this problem has different solutions. The best one I found is to split the loop to two parts using "Sub Orchestrator".

```
[FunctionName("Orchestrator")]
public static async Task<bool> RunOrchestrator(
[OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger logger)
{

    List<string> hashKeyList = new List<string>();
  

    foreach (var a in A)//LOOP A
    {
       //CALL SUB ORCHESTRATOR

         hashKeyList = await context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync<List<string>>
                (nameof(SecondOrchestrator), (hashKeyList , a));
      }
   }
```

and the Sub Orchestrator code would be:

```
 [FunctionName("SecondOrchestrator")]
    public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
       [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger logger)
    {
        (List<string> HashkeyIdList,A a)
         = context.GetInput<(List<string>, A)>();
        List<Task<CalcResult>> tasksList = new List<Task<CalcResult>>();
    Dictionary<A, B> otherCalc = new Dictionary<A, B>();
    List<FinalResult> finalResults = new List<FinalResult>();

     foreach (var b in B)//LOOP B
        {
            var hashKey = doSomeThingOnAandB(a, b);
        if (!hashKeyList.Contains(hashKey))
            {
                hashkeyList.Add(hashKey);
                tasksList.Add(context.CallActivityAsync<CalcResult>
                    (nameof(CalculationActivity), (a, b)));
            }
        else
            {
                otherCalc.Add(a, b);
            }
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasksList);

        foreach (var task in tasksList)
        {
            var res = ((Task<caclResult>)task).Result;
          //DO WHAT IS NEEDED WITH FINALRESULTS OR RETURN TO MAIN ORCHESTRATOR

            finalResults.Add(res); 
        }
      return HashkeyIdList;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from the code, your outer loop shouldn't be restarting over and over again, but you never remove the finished tasks from your taskList after reading their result:

```
foreach (var task in tasksList)
{
    var res = ((Task<caclResult>)task).Result; //should be "CalcResult"?
    finalResults.Add(res);
}
```

I suspect you are missing

```
tasksList.Clear();
```

after this foreach loop or at the start of the outer loop.

Alternatively, is there a specific reason you have to read your task results inside the for loop? Why not just await all the added tasks after your outer loop has finished? Not only do you avoid reading the results multiple times, but I suspect letting all tasks be created first and then awaiting them should be faster, since your threading doesn't have to wait on the last thread(s) multiple times, and instead already work on the next task.

```
outer foreach
{
    inner foreach
    {
    ...
    }
...
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasksList);

foreach (var task in tasksList)
{
    var res = ((Task<caclResult>)task).Result;

    finalResults.Add(res);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I should say 1)the reason I didn't call taskList.Clear() inside the loop or any other place is the strange behaviour, it get's cleared before it is done. 2) having await Task.WhenAll(TaskList) at the last line out of the loop works when your outer "foreach" is a reasonable amount. My loop is for "Millions" or itteration. I get out of memory.

Comment: Can you provide the minimal code needed to reproduce your issue? The code above is very abstract, and we can't really know what is happening, with A and B being placeholders and things like taskResult and doSomethingOnAandB being unknown

Comment: I tried to have an abstract code, to reduce involvement in Business concepts. I am reconsidering that maybe "Durable functions" is not a good idea in general; Because of "EVENT SOURCING" design pattern they follow. Maybe, whenever we have huge nested loops we have to use other Azure services. In the solution I offered (I mean Sub Orchestrator ) the outer loops traces (but not process) line by line until each time it reaches to the "execute row" (call of sub orchestrator). That means it is working fine in the first 50 loops, it starts to get slow after 100 iterations.